# Returning false in OnTouch on ImageView but still event is getting consumed

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I am using `ImageView.onTouch()`.
I am returning false for `ACTION_MOVE` but still the `onTouch()` event is consumed.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                System.out.println("jan25 iv onTouch");

                if (ev.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    System.out.println("jan25 iv ACTION_DOWN");
                    return true;
                }

                if (ev.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    System.out.println("jan25 iv ACTION_MOVE");
                    return false;

                }
                if (ev.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    System.out.println("jan25 iv ACTION_UP");
                    return true;
                }

                System.out.println("jan25 iv false");
                return false;

            }
        });
```

Layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_magic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/abcd"
             />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any idea please

Comment: Did you try to step through with the debugger?

Comment: ofcourse. I had printed all statement.

Comment: @corsair992 May be. But I am testing on jelly bean. Still facing

Comment: Hmm, yes it looks like you can only indicate touch handling on the initial down event. I would consider this to be a bug, although it's unlikely to be fixed now. Still, you might want to report it on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that returning `false` from the `onTouchEvent()` callback of a view is only effective when receiving the first motion event with `ACTION_DOWN`. Setting an `OnTouchListener` on a non-consuming view has the same semantics. This seems to be a bug in the `dispatchTouchEvent()` implementation in `ViewGroup`. It doesn't seem likely that it will be fixed after such a long time though, as that would break implementations that incorrectly depend on this behavior.

As a workaround, you can set a flag indicating the handling of touch events, and check that before handling. This flag should be reset upon receiving the `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL` motion events.

Comment: In my case I need the parent handle the touchs after I evaluate some logics on ACTION_MOVE, what can I do ?

Comment: @diegoveloper: If the parent is a custom implementation that you can modify, then you can try to achieve this by overriding it's `onInterceptTouchEvent()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

From:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have multiple actions that follow each other. So, if you return false when the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions from this event. Thus, you will not be called for any other actions within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action event.

So returning false should not consume the event. How did you determine that the event was consumed?

Comment: "jan25 iv onTouch" still getting called after returning the false. But if I do same for ACTION_DOWN, "jan25 iv onTouch" is not getting called.

Comment: I am moving the figure,  so ACTION_MOVE is continuously calling. but I am returning false, so It should not called after one call

Comment: Just remember, down is called when the finger first touches, move if moving, then up.  What exactly are you wanting to do?  Worst case you could set a boolean surrounding the on move and then reset in on up.

Comment: Please check the " So, if you return false when the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions from this event." part. So returning false from ACTION_MOVE will not have effect.

Answer (score 0):

This works too, but I'm still not 100% sure what you are asking to do.  This sets the imageView clickable to false and should therefore allow the touch not to be consumed by it.  Also, I added clickable to the LinearLayout.

```
 imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
            System.out.println("jan25 iv onTouch");

            if (ev.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("jan25 iv ACTION_DOWN");
                return true;
            }

            if (ev.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                System.out.println("jan25 iv ACTION_MOVE");
                imageView.setClickable(false);
                return false;

            }
            if (ev.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                System.out.println("jan25 iv ACTION_UP");
                return true;
            }

            System.out.println("jan25 iv false");
            return false;

        }
    });

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_magic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:clickable = "true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abcd"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: imageview is within linearlayout. and both having touch listener. so when image view is having touch listener, linear layout touch is not getting called. As per my requirement I have to stop the touch of imageview from Action_move so that linear layout can have.

Comment: You could maybe set the imageView.setClickable(false) if you don't need it again after registering the touch in the ll.  Also, do you have the ll set to clickable?