# android: what's the impact if OnTouchEvent returning false when ACTION_MOVE?

Tags: android, view

About `ACTION_DOWN`, if return false in the view's `onTouchEvent` function, we could not receive the following

> ACTION_MOVE
>
> ACTION_UP
>
> ACTION_CANCEL

but what's the impact when returning false when ACTION_MOVE? like

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

I tested with a `listview` and seemed ok..

Comment: I thing  same effect

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning false in OnTouch on ImageView but still event is getting consumed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067270/returning-false-in-ontouch-on-imageview-but-still-event-is-getting-consumed)

Answer (score 1):

When the onTouchEvent returns false for ACTION_DOWN, the view will not receive further calls of onTouchEvent, and the parent view will receive a call of onTouchEvent with ACTION_DOWN, and the parent view will decide whether to handle the touch event or not by returning true for yes, false for no

If the view returns true for ACTION_DOWN, but returns false for ACTION_MOVE, it will continue to get onTouchEvent calls, the parent view will not receive any onTouchEvent calls, it seems that the idea is this touch sequence has already been decided to be handled by this view, so even if the view returns false half way, we still wouldn't start calling onTouchEvent on the parent view

However, the Activity hosting the view will receive an onTouchEvent call everytime this view returns false for a non ACTION_DOWN onTouchEvent call, it just is the case, and it perhaps is not an reasonable result anyone would want

Comment: In my case I need the parent handle the touchs after I evaluate some logics on ACTION_MOVE,  how can I do ?