# OnTouch return false but event still consumed

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Similar thread : [Returning false in OnTouch on ImageView but still event is getting consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067270/returning-false-in-ontouch-on-imageview-but-still-event-is-getting-consumed)

Basically I registered a `OnTouch` listener on a `CardView`, `Relative Layout` and a `Recycler View` and return `false` for all of the methods with the following XML :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view_list_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_list_item_text_memo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow">



        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_photos_memo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As per my understanding, if the OnTouch method return false, then the siblings/parents view handler method will be called instead. The weird part is when I clicked on the area of `RecyclerView` , the same `OnTouch` listener handler of the `RecyclerView` keeps getting called despite the return value being false. However if i click on the area of `RelativeLayout` outside of `RecyclerView`, it functions as per usual (it calls the `onTouch` of `CardView` and prints the log information).
From the thread I linked above, some users are apparently saying it's a bug in Android. So is it really so, or did I miss something?

EDIT : Here's the only listener implementation in my project. The following codes are inside an adapter holder (specifically inside the constructor method of the holder) on separate class from the adapter :

```
    ...
   cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_list_text);
    photosRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_photos_memo);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_list_item_text_memo);

    photosRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("recyclerview called");
            return false;
        }
    });
    relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            System.out.println("RELATIVELAYOUT called");
            return false;
        }
    });

    cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("CARDVIEW CALLED");
            return false;
        }
    });
   ...
```

Comment: Could you share the code where you set and use your listeners?

Comment: @antonio ok, I just updated my post :)